# JPA with Couchbase?

Tags: java, jpa, couchbase

I will create an application that needs both structured and unstructured data. For the unstructured part a relational database will be clumsy. When looking for options, I stumbled over Couchbase which seems to happily store the unstructured documents while it has SQL92 compatibility with N1QL. So now I am thinking whether Couchbase could cover the structured data requirements as well.

Has anyone had success with the combination JPA and Couchbase?

Comment: Hello, could you please elaborate on the Structured part of your needs? Couchbase can run distributed SQL with JOINs and transaction support for instance. There is however no supported JPA project that I know of. The closest bit could be Spring Data Couchbase.

Comment: It would be simple entity beans. POJOs with at most a refernce to another enitity, but no inheritance or whatsoever. While I believe you are right, somehow I hoped there would be a JDBC driver that could be used underneath Hibernate or similar.

Comment: There is a Couchbase implementation of Spring Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I found [Object-Relational Mapping with Couchbase Data Entities in Java](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/couchbase-jdbc-hibernate.rst):

> You can use Hibernate to map object-oriented domain models to a
> traditional relational database. The tutorial below shows how to use
> the CData JDBC Driver for Couchbase to generate an ORM of your
> Couchbase repository with Hibernate.

The above claims to work on Hibernate, which itself is a JPA provider.
If it works I will prefer this solution over non-JPA solutions.

We found two commercially offered JDBC drivers for Couchbase: [CDATA](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/couchbase/jdbc/) and [Simba](https://insightsoftware.com/de/drivers/couchbase-odbc-jdbc/). Both of them did not cover our requirements so we dropped the idea of storing everything in Couchbase.